# Difference usage of document level, sentence level and aspect level in sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm studying about Sentiment analysis. What is the purpose of using Document Level, Sentence Level and Aspect Level?

I read this definition in Web Data Mining book by Bing liu.

In this book it was stated that,

Sentence Level sentiment analysis is to classify a sentence to negative, positive, neutral class.

Document level sentiment analysis to classify a document.

Aspect Level sentiment analysis is to classify each aspect of entity mentioned in a review.

Thanks.

Comment: A reference to where you had read this would be helpful

Comment: @KiriteeGak yes, I've added the reference book, where I red this difination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am building on Toros91's answer. He has said:

> Use case of all these 3 different levels are:
>
> ```
> Sentence Level: Used to classify a sentences for instance, whether a tweet is positive or negative or neutral.
> Document Level: Used to classify the whole document level to say whether that document sentiment is positive or negative or neutral.
> Aspect Level: Used to select an aspect and give the outcome of that respective Aspect, for instance let us consider Iphone X as an
> ```
>
> aspect and mine tweets(this is an example you can use documents and so
>   on) and carry out Sentiment Analysis.

Now, to answer your question further about how it can be beneficial, just take an example of some review. I am just forming my own review on something as an example, I do not know the specifics, so please do not quote me here. This has some business logic implied as well.

> I feel the latest laptop from Mac is really good overall. It has
>   amazing resolution. The computer is really very sleek and can slide
>   into bags easily. However, I feel the weight is a let down. The price
>   is a bit expensive given the configurations. I expect an SSD storage.
>   However, the processor seems really good.

At a document level, I can say the entire paragraph looks more positive than negative. So, the review, if has to be labeled as one thing, is positive.

At a sentence level, I can break the document into 6 sentences and classify each of them as positive, negative or neutral. I get a bit more specific here.

Finally, at an aspect level, I get information about price, storage, processor and so on.

Given N customer reviews, you can know how well different aspects of a particular product are received. Say, 10 customers feel the price is fine, but 4 feel it is expensive. 13 of your 14 customers really love the resolution while 1 feel it is okayish. A lot of products in day to day life have multiple things to be considered. And this is where fine grained labeling help analysts or scientists.

Comment: Would you have some code examples for aspect level sentiment?